# PHP use of undefinined constant error

Tags: php

Hey getting an error on my code can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Notice: Use of undefined constant folder - assumed 'folder' in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\gallery.php on line 74

Notice: Use of undefined constant folder - assumed 'folder' in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\gallery.php on line 75

Here's the relevant section

```
     $path = "./images/gallery";
  $results = scandir($path);

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result !== "." and $result !== ".." and $result !== ".DS_Store"){
    //only lists the folders we want

        $folders[] = $result;
      } 
  }

  echo "<h2 id=\"galleryheaders\">";

    foreach ($folders as $folder){
      echo "<a href=\"gallery.php?folder=$folder\">$folder</a>\n";
    }



  foreach ($folders as $folder){
      echo "<?gallery = . $folder>";

    }

  echo "</h2>";

  if (isset($_GET[folder])) {
    $gallery = $_GET[folder];
  }else { 
    $gallery = $folders[0];
    };
```

the lines it specifically mentions are those last 2 folders

Comment: Try this `echo "<a href=\"gallery.php?folder=".$folder."\">".$folder."</a>\n";` in place of `echo "<a href=\"gallery.php?folder=$folder\">$folder</a>\n";`

Comment: Which are lines 74 and 75?

Comment: Are you sure this is line 74-75? I don't see anything from my understanding that would generate this notice. Normally, it's generated when you forget to prefix a variable with $, and PHP assumes it's a constant.

Comment: Quote your associative array indexes, otherwise PHP assumes that an unquoted text value is a constant: `if (isset($_GET['folder'])) {
    $gallery = $_GET['folder'];
  }else { 
    $gallery = $folders[0];
    };`

Comment: Please note what you changed in your original comment. Relevant code was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around your strings:

```
if (isset($_GET[folder])) {
    $gallery = $_GET[folder];
}
```

should be:

```
if (isset($_GET['folder'])) {
    $gallery = $_GET['folder'];
}
```